# Can I ask what is the principle of dynamic config in temporal?

Tags: temporal-workflow

Can I ask what is the principle of dynamic config in temporal?

When changing content of dynamic config, how long matching services change config based on it really?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic config allows you to update parts of server configuration without having to restart your services. It includes a lot of fine-tuning knobs like rps limits, qps limits etc (more info [here](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/blob/master/common/dynamicconfig/constants.go)).

As far as the update interval, you can set it via your static config, see for example in default config template https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/blob/master/docker/config_template.yaml#L379-L381. Min value for update you can set ins 5s.